# Replace elements using Jsoup, Android

Tags: android, jsoup

Does anyone know how to replace elements using Jsoup. Im trying to replace table elements and their content with buttons but having no success. Code attempt is below. This is for an android project

```
Elements elements = doc.select("table");
         if (elements != null) {
            for (Element element : elements) {
                Element button = Jsoup.parse("<button type='button'>Click Me!</button>");
                element.replaceWith(button);
            }
         }
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the content of the table or the table itself? As of now, you are selecting all the tables on the site and replace them with a button, which I don't think is what you want? Please post the HTML of the site you want to replace the tags in and what your desired result is.

Answer (score 0):

I went about this in a bit of a hacky way it seems to work. The replaceWith(button) attribute did'nt do anything. I do actually want to replace the whole table with a button but i also want to add that button along with the results to a string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    Element sibling = siblings.get(i);
    if ("table".equals(sibling.tagName())) {
        siblings.remove(i);
        Element button = Jsoup.parse("<button type='button'>Click Me!</button>");
        sibling = button;
        sb.append(sibling.toString());
     } 
    else {
        sb.append(sibling.toString());
    }
}
```